# Conversion of DDL Statement to DDL Statement issued via Spark program or via Hive

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a SQL query to a spark program . In the SQL query I encountered a tag (distribution = replicate). First I created a hive query out of it and trying to execute the same.

How do I take care of this in hive sql? Code is as below.

```
create table LAAD_REFRESH_JOB_LOG
    (
    col1 datetime,
    col2 varchar(20),
    col3 varchar(20),
    col4 varchar(200),
    col5 int
    )with (distribution = replicate);
```

I have converted the above to below:

```
create table LAAD_REFRESH_JOB_LOG(
    col1 TIMESTAMP,
    col2 STRING,
    col3 STRING,
    col4 STRING,
    col5 INT
    )
    STORED AS PARQUET
    TBLPROPERTIES ('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY');
```

But how do I take care of (distribution = replicate) . is the above hve query correct or do I have to need to do any modifications

Comment: yes . your solution gives me clue that I need not to worry about property (distribution = replicate) , as I am using yarn beneath the spark and replication is already taken care of  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely nothing as in hdfs-site.xml the replication factor for the cluster is typically set as follows:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>                <!--  Here you need to set replication factor for entire cluster. -->     
</property>
```

You can set it per Spark Job so I am told, but my advice is to concentrate on functionality and not worry about low cost storage. When using S3 more redundancy is also evident, but the cost is so cheap it's ridiculous.

From your question it is unclear if you would be using Spark SQL or just native Hive BTW.